# «Двигатель стерлинг дельфин». Как писать: без кавычек, со строчной?

Tags: выбор-слов

«Двигатель стерлинг дельфин». Как писать? Без кавычек, со строчной?

Answer (score 1):

Принято писать **двигатель «Стерлинг-Дельфин»**, это конкретная марка двигателя. В общем случае пишут **двигатель Стерлинга.**

Примеры:

Скорость до двадцати узлов, два **двигателя «Стерлинг-Дельфин»** по триста сил каждый.

Канлодка имела два шестицилиндровых бензиновых **мотора «Стерлинг-Дельфин»** мощностью по 225 л.с. при 1200 об/мин, два вала и два гребных винта.

Для справок:  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0

**Дви́гатель Стеррлинга —** тепловая машина, в которой рабочее тело, в виде газа или жидкости, движется в замкнутом объёме, разновидность двигателя внешнего сгорания.  Может работать не только от сжигания топлива, но и от любого источника тепла.

Comment: Пишут «Стерлинг-Дельфин» и «Стерлинг Дельфин». Но что это по сути? Мотор "Дельфин Стирлинга"? В первоисточнике Sterling Dolphin engine.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [этой брошюре](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077NG61M7), "Стерлинг" — это название фирмы, "Дельфин" (или "Долфин") — это одна из моделей лодочных двигателей данной фирмы (наряду с моделями "Нептун" и "Викинг", например).

Поэтому можно писать "двигатель модели "Дельфин" фирмы «Стерлинг»" или, короче, "двигатель «Стерлинг-Дельфин»".

Да, и эти двигатели внутреннего сгорания никакого отношения к машине Стирлинга не имеют.

Comment: «Судя из» — лишь дважды числится в НКРЯ, причём из них одно от XIX в., а второе — свежее (комментарий с некоего форума).

Comment: - Ловите! Буквоед в треде!!!11

("Ссылаясь на каталог компании "Стерлинг" 1931 года издания, позволю себе сказать, что..." - так лучше, полегчало?)

Comment: В гугло-книгах можно найти множество примеров ошибочного употребления "судя из", но это тоже не оправдание. Поскольку считаю ответ полезным, я внёс небольшие правки и поддержал его.